# Download Firebird Version 2.5.5

Tags: database, firebird, firebird2.5

Where do I download the above version of Firebird which has corrected [this issue](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-4830)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2.5.5 version is not officially released yet. If you want to test then you could use the snapshot build, available at http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/snapshot-builds/

Comment: Thank you. Clearly I was not quite awake when posting this

Answer (score 0):

Firebird 2.5.5 was just released: http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5-5/
It is really good idea to upgrade to 2.5.5, since 2.5.3 and 2.5.4 had unpleasant issues with hanging on Services API calls.